# Adding rules to custom fields

Tags: tfs-workitem

I have modified the WIT for a bug and added 2 custom fields, i.e. PartDetails (a drop down with 3 values, "01 P1 Demo", "02 P2 Exec" and "03 P2 Config") and Parts (again a drop down with 2 values, "P1" and "P2").
I'd like to add rules as follows.
when adding a bug, if the user selects "01 P1 Demo", Parts drop down should automatically select "P1". Similarly if the user selects "02 P2 Exec" or "03 P2 Config" Parts drop down will automatically select "P2".

I am playing with the combinations of MATCH and COPY elements but not able to crack it. Any suggestions?

The rule needs to be as follows: If PartDetails value starts with '01' select 'P1' in Parts drop down etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194947.aspx#Dependent